# how to change href during onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dynamic hyperlink that will download an image retrieved from the server.

The code I am using:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn" id="controlDownloadJPEG" download>Save & Download</a>
```

JS:

```
this.downloadJPEGClickHandler = function() {
    CollageCore.downloadJPEG(function(data){
        $("#controlDownloadJPEG").attr("href", "../file/fileStore.action?fileName=/" + data[0].AttachmentUrl);
    });;
    return true;
};
```

The href is getting changed on click, but the link itself is linking to the href set before my JavaScript executes. The first click does nothing as there is no default href and the second click will download what the first click should have downloaded.

I have seen suggestions to use JavaScript window.href instead of relying on the html tag itself. The reason I need to use the html tag is for its download functionality.

Comment: have you tried binding the click-handler in the capturing-phase?

Comment: That is what happens when you enter the world of asynchronous calls. The click does not wait around.

Comment: Might help use `$("#controlDownloadJPEG").get(0).click();` after setting href

Comment: @Satpal not going to help when the page already has left

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prevent the default click behavior, change the href attribute, and then imitate the click. Should work.

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#controlDownloadJPEG").attr("href", "../file/fileStore.action?fileName=/" + data[0].AttachmentUrl);
  $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are treating an asynchronous call as it it is synchronous. It is like ordering a delivery pizza and expecting it to be there as soon as you place the order. That does not happen unless you are standing in the restaurant and it is already been made.

You need to cancel the click and fire the page change manually when the call comes back. So you want to use `window.location.href = "new path";` instead of setting the href.

```
this.downloadJPEGClickHandler = function() {
    CollageCore.downloadJPEG(function(data){
        window.location.href = "../file/fileStore.action?fileName=/" + data[0].AttachmentUrl;
    });
    return false;  //or preventDefault if you pass in event object
};
```

Comment: So set the href and fire the click event or set the proper headers to force the download.

Answer (score 0):

If you are are attaching this activity to an `onClick(event)` handler you should be able to stop the redirect by passing in `event.preventDefault();`

cite: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/